# Select union in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I created this stored procedure using `postgresql` :

```
 create or replace Function GetTimeStamp(
    IN t1 timestamp ,
    IN t2 timestamp ,
    Out reg_os Varchar(50),
    Out customer_count int ,
    Out t5 timestamp
    ) returns void AS $$
    Begin

    SELECT payment.payment_ts AS t , customer.registration_os As os ,count(Distinct customer.customer_id) As total
    From customer inner join payment on customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
    Where Payment.payment_ts Between t1 And t2 
    Group By 1 , 2
    Union
    SELECT transfer.ts_created AS t , customer.registration_os As os, count(Distinct customer.customer_id) As total 
    From customer inner join account on customer.customer_id = account.customer_id inner join transfer on account.account_id = transfer.from_account
    Where transfer.ts_created Between t1 And t2 
    Group By 1 , 2;
    select t , os , total into t5 , reg_os , customer_count ;
    End;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am able to create the stored procedure , however when I use this code:

```
 SELECT GetTimeStamp('2016-01-01' ,'2017-01-01')   OR  
 SELECT * FROM GetTimeStamp('2016-01-01' ,'2017-01-01')
```

It gives me an error:

> query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to discard
>   the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead

.

I used perform instead of select in the stored procedure and it gave me

> Syntax Error near PERFORM.

I don't know if I can use a union between two perform queries.How can I get the result of this stored procedure?

Comment: *Syntax Error near PERFROM* -- it's `PERFORM`, not *PERFROM*

Comment: @pozs its a typo i edited it

Comment: then please give us the code example where you call this function with `PERFORM`. Maybe just a semicolon is missing from the statement above it.

Comment: @pozs PERFORM GetTimeStamp('2016-01-01' , '2017-01-01');  it gives me                                      :syntax error at or near "PERFORM". I also tried using perfom instead of sql in the stored procedure but it gives me the same error.

Comment: The whole context please, inside your question (it is usually hard to read code from comments).

Comment: Also, your `GetTimeStamp` function doesn't make much sense, since it does not "get" anything (`returns void`). In this form it should produce the first error you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

In PL/pgSQL, you need to use `SELECT ... INTO` to specify the variables where the result should be stored. To discard the result, use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [return a set (`table`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE) and it can be plain `SQL`

```
create or replace Function GetTimeStamp (
   IN t1 timestamp ,
   IN t2 timestamp
) returns table (
    reg_os Varchar(50),
    customer_count int,
    t5 timestamp
) language sql as $$

    SELECT
        payment.payment_ts AS t ,
        customer.registration_os As os ,
        count(Distinct customer.customer_id) As total
    From
        customer
        inner join
        payment on customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
    Where Payment.payment_ts Between t1 And t2 
    Group By 1 , 2

    Union

    SELECT
        transfer.ts_created AS t ,
        customer.registration_os As os,
        count(Distinct customer.customer_id) As total 
    From
        customer
        inner join
        account on customer.customer_id = account.customer_id
        inner join
        transfer on account.account_id = transfer.from_account
    Where transfer.ts_created Between t1 And t2 
    Group By 1 , 2;
$$;
```

Comment: I used this perform , however it returned one row with one column cotaining nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by returned? From the function? Your function returns void so that is expected. If you want different then change its return type.